# angular ng-app="demoApp" does not work for me

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular. The code have been just working fine so far but it seem to stop working when I use ng-app="demoApp" or any other app directives. It cannot bind on controllers. This is my view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Learn AngularJS->Binding on the Controllers</title>  

</head>

<body>

<div class="container" ng-app="demoApp" data-ng-controller="simpleController">
<h3>Adding a simple Controller</h3>

<ul>

<li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers"> 
{{cust.name}} - {{cust.city}}

</li>

</ul>

</div>
```

this is my js/controller/simpleController.js

```
 var app = angular.module('demoApp',[]);
   var app = angular.module('demoApp',[]);
app.controller('simpleController',function($scope)
{
$scope.customers=[
{name:'John Smith',{city:'Kitale'},
{name:'Jane Martins',{city:'Bungoma'},
{name:'Esther Williams',{city:'Busia'},
{name:'James Anthony',{city:'Nakuru'},
{name:'Irine seniorman',{city:'Eldoret'},
{name:'Agrey Ngoya',{city:'Kitui'},
{name:'Anne Chemos',{city:'Bomet'},
{name:'Zacheous Waweru',{city:'Murang\'a'}

];

});
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/angular-1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/controller/simpleController.js"></script>
```

This is what am getting in the browser after including the ng-app=demoApp" directive as indicated in my view above:

```
Adding a simple Controller

{{cust.name}} - {{cust.city}}
```

But when I remove the ng-app="demoApp" the other code works just fine. Something I don't understand is the ng-app directive is not working for me. Other directives are working fine but also stop working the app directive is used anywhere in the code. I have checked to ensure that the app directive is not used twice in the code but with no success at all. Any help please, what I may getting wrong. I cannot find any error.

Comment: Load your JS file in html like `<script src='js/controller/simpleController.js'></script>`

Comment: see the answer below. Maybe that will help you, your definition for $scope.customers is wrong. You can check the plunker and see what you can do with the codes you have. upvote and ticking it correct, makes the helper want to help more :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were some errors in your customers array copy paste the code below and try it again.

Html

```
<body ng-app="demoApp">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="simpleController">
      <h3>Adding a simple Controller</h3>

      <ul>

      <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers"> 
      {{cust.name}} - {{cust.city}}

      </li>

      </ul>

    </div>
  </body>
```

Controller.js

```
var app = angular.module('demoApp',[]);

app.controller('simpleController',['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.customers=[
    {name:'John Smith',city:'Kitale'},
    {name:'Jane Martins',city:'Bungoma'},
    {name:'Esther Williams',city:'Busia'},
    {name:'James Anthony',city:'Nakuru'},
    {name:'Irine seniorman',city:'Eldoret'},
    {name:'Agrey Ngoya',city:'Kitui'},
    {name:'Anne Chemos',city:'Bomet'},
    {name:'Zacheous Waweru',city:'Murang\'a'}
  ];
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, it now works. It was just of issues you have pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

> Your array definition is wrong.

**NO:** `{name:'John Smith',{city:'Kitale'}`
**YES:** `{name:'John Smith',city:'Kitale'}`

**Here is the working Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/hC3iY8HUG23N7DjIS2hP?p=preview

SO, your overall Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" ng-app="demoApp" data-ng-controller="simpleController">
        <h3>Adding a simple Controller</h3>
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers">
                {{cust.name}} - {{cust.city}}
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('demoApp', []);
        app.controller('simpleController', function($scope) {
            $scope.customers = [{
                    name: 'John Smith',
                    city: 'Kitale'
                }, {
                    name: 'Jane Martins',
                    city: 'Bungoma'
                }, {
                    name: 'Esther Williams',
                    city: 'Busia'
                }, {
                    name: 'James Anthony',
                    city: 'Nakuru'
                }, {
                    name: 'Irine seniorman',
                    city: 'Eldoret'
                }, {
                    name: 'Agrey Ngoya',
                    city: 'Kitui'
                }, {
                    name: 'Anne Chemos',
                    city: 'Bomet'
                }, {
                    name: 'Zacheous Waweru',
                    city: 'Murang\'a'
                }

            ];

        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex Rumba Nicked. It works. I real appreciate your assitance.

Comment: glad i could be of some help.